# Synchronizing ETL and reads on the Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, data-warehouse, etl

I have the following **scenario**:

- ETL loads data into the DW.
- Reports run on demand, maybe at the same time with the ETL, consuming data from the DW.

**And this my problem:** I need to make sure the reports do not contain partial data:

- If reports are running when ETL is ready to load data, ETL must wait for reports to complete.
- If ETL is loading and a report is requested, report must wait for ETL to finish.
- If ETL is waiting to load and a report is requested, report must wait for ETL to run and finish - ETL always has priority over reports.

What is the best mechanism to get this? Database locks do not seem to be intelligent enough to manage the priorities I need.

Should I implement my own locking mechanism? If yes, is there a well-known design for it? Many things must be taken into account: keep track of currently running reports (lock-for-reads), implement lock expiration for cases when the ETL fails notifying it finished, etc.

Comment: Are your reports run via a scheduled job? Or are you using an ad-hoc tool?

Comment: Reports can be requested on demand (by the user through the GUI) and can be requested by a scheduled job. Reports are generated by a reporting tool that reads from DW. At the moment of "starting" a report we need to know whether the report will run immediately or will wait for ETL to run/complete - to notify the consumer.

Comment: Is this reporting tool home grown or a 3rd party application like Microstrategy or Cognos?

Comment: Your guess was correct. We use Cognos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Cognos, then I think you're basically out of luck from a "prevent report from running if ETL is running" kind of set up, unless you want to muck about in badly-documented APIs.

Your best bet is to probably identify the specific reports, usually ones that are run against aggregates, and make sure that you set up your ETL process to update the facts and aggregates last, and as one big "update" transaction. If you use a dbms that gives you read-consistency, you should be able to do this without a report showing up with only half the data loaded to it.

Reports that access multiple facts / multiple aggs will be more troublesome. It may even be that you may have to set up some kind of "table swap" where you build what you need then `alter table rename` to swap out the tables.

Comment: Unfortunately our ETL needs to open multiple "small" transactions. Besides, our reports are defined dinamically, so we can't identify which data will consume each. Swapping tables sounds like a clean solution, but still needs synchronization: reports must not run while tables are being swapped. Also with swapping we would be creating a copy of a huge amount of data.

Comment: @romanws Agreed that you'd be copying a large amount of data. You may want to contact Cognos support to see if there's a way to block reports from running based on an external flag of some sort, then you could set that flag when your ETL is running. I'm not a cognos expert, but most of those BI tools tend to have an API that can control some things...

Comment: I did, and IBM answered: "Cognos does not have a mechanism to 'hold' request as of now [...] this would be an Enhancement Request". This is, the feature is not built-in, but they could implement it, and charge us for that - not exactly what we want :)

Comment: In conclusion: we decided to code our own mechanism based on semaphores, queues, priorities, tokens, etc. Thanks @n-west for your comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the etl process set a flag in a record in a table when it starts and unset it when it completes?  The Reporting system can then query this table to see if the flag is set and notify the user that the warehouse is running and either put the report in a queue that is processed on completion of the ETL process or tell the user to try later.  If you want to allow users to use facts that have been processed, your flag table would need to be at the table grain - i.e. on flag record per table.

Comment: Reports might be running when ETL is ready to start. We need ETL to wait for current reports to complete, but no new reports to start while ETL is running. We also had other complicated requirements (like: if system goes down while a report or ETL was blocked, the operation must run on startup), so we decided to implement our own mechanism.